# Elixir update specific value key within nested map

Tags: elixir

I have as input the following Map

```elixir
temp = %{
  "temperature" => %{
    "details" => "Temperature Template",
    "sensors" => [
      %{
        "name" => "TMP",
        "type" => "integer",
        "value" => 0
      },
      %{
        "name" => "DEEP_SLEEP",
        "type" => "integer",
        "value" => 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I now need to update the key `"value" => 10` from 10 to 15 related with the key `"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP"`

started by updating the nested map

```elixir
new_sensor =
  temp
  |> Map.get("temperature")
  |> Map.get("sensors")
  |> Enum.find(fn x -> x["name"] == "DEEP_SLEEP" end)
  |> Map.put("value", 15)

%{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 15}
```

Now trying to get one level up

```elixir
new_device =
  temp
  |> Map.get("temperature")
  |> Map.put("sensors", %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 15})

%{
  "details" => "Temperature Template",
  "sensors" => %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 15}
}
```

Now I should be able to rebuild the map with something like:

```elixir
Map.put(temp, "temperature", new_device)
```

But the outcome is not correct

```elixir
iex(32)> Map.put(temp, "temperature", new_device)
%{
  "temperature" => %{
    "details" => "Temperature Template",
    "sensors" => %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 15}
  }
}
iex(33)> temp
%{
  "temperature" => %{
    "details" => "Temperature Template",
    "sensors" => [
      %{"name" => "TMP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 0},
      %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 10}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick would be to update an array and then update the map with it’s new value:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ old_value = temp["temperature"]["sensors"]
#⇒ [
#   %{"name" => "TMP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 0},
#   %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 10}
# ]
```

We’ll explicitly pattern-match the function parameters to update only this map with `"DEEP_SLEEP"` name.

```rb
iex|2 ▶ new_value = Enum.map(old_value, fn                         
...|2 ▷   %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP"} = subj ->
...|2 ▷     %{subj | "value" => subj["value"] + 5}
...|2 ▷   subj -> subj
...|2 ▷ end)
#⇒ [
#   %{"name" => "TMP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 0},
#   %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "type" => "integer", "value" => 15}
# ]
```

Now we might use [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3) to update the original map:

```rb
iex|3 ▶ put_in(temp, ~w|temperature sensors|, new_value)
```

---

Another option would be to use [`Kernel.get_and_update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_and_update_in/3).

Comment: Thanks, work as charm .... now trying to make it more generic, like,
- Provide the "name" key value
- check which "type" match etc

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3) for this scenario.

```
map = %{
  nested: %{
    keys: 5
  }
}

put_in(map, [:nested, :keys], 10)
=> %{nested: %{keys: 10}}
```

Comment: `Kernel.put_in/3` as it is won’t allow to selectively update nested maps based on the value of the `name` key.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way

```elixir
    put_in(
      temp, 
      ["temperature", "sensors"], 
      update_in(
        temp["temperature"]["sensors"], 
        [Access.filter(&(&1["name"] == "DEEP_SLEEP")), "value"], 
        fn _ -> 15 end)
      )
```

1 first you `update_in` the nested value, then you `put_in` the updated nested list within the map

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using [`update_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/2):

```elixir
update_in(temp["temperature"]["sensors"], fn items ->
  Enum.map(items, fn
    %{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP", "value" => value} = item -> %{item | "value" => value + 5}
    item -> item
  end)
end)
```

---

Another one, inspired by @MoVod's use of `Access.filter`:

```elixir
update_in(
  temp,
  [
    Access.key!("temperature"),
    Access.key!("sensors"),
    Access.filter(&match?(%{"name" => "DEEP_SLEEP"}, &1))
  ],
  fn %{"value" => value} = item -> %{item | "value" => value + 5} end
)
```

Comment: nice! The second one really rocks! Thanks

Comment: It also makes it very easy to update the  complete item. Very useful when updating a record list in `socket.assigns`